# linq2sql IQueryable Predicate, cannot filter SQL table records

Tags: c#, sql, linq, iqueryable, predicate

i have searched through many posts and i still cannot achieve my desired result.

I have a aspx page with 3 comboboxes, and a search button.
when the user clicks on the search button i want to build a linq query that will only return the result from the the filters selected in the comboboxes and bind it to a gridview.

The comboboxes Are Account, Site and Transaction, i am searching through logs and would only like to return the of the selected comboboxes futhermore if a selection is not made from the combobox the addition to the query is ignored.

On button click

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This is the Linq definition
        List<Expression<Func<Logs, bool>>> predicates = new List<Expression<Func<Logs, bool>>>();

        if (Convert.ToInt32(cboAccount.SelectedValue) != -1)
        {
            var accountID = Convert.ToInt32(cboAccount.SelectedValue);
            predicates.Add(p => p.accountID == accountID);
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt32(cboSite.SelectedValue) != -1)
        {
            var siteID = Convert.ToInt32(cboSite.SelectedValue);
            predicates.Add(p => p.siteID == siteID);
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt32(cboTransactionType.SelectedValue) != -1)
        {
            var transID = Convert.ToInt32(cboTransactionType.SelectedValue);
            predicates.Add(p => p.transactionID == transID);
        }

        rgLog.DataSource = Logs.LoadLogs(predicates);
    }
```

Method inside my Logs Class

```
    public class Logs
{

    private int AccountID;
    private int SiteID;
    private string SerialNumber;
    private int UserID;
    private int TransActionMessageID;

    public int accountID
    {
        get { return AccountID; }
        set { AccountID = value; }
    }

    public int siteID
    {
        get { return SiteID; }
        set { SiteID = value; }
    }

    public string serialNumber
    {
        get { return SerialNumber; }
        set { SerialNumber = value; }
    }

    public int userID
    {
        get { return UserID; }
        set { UserID = value; }
    }

    public int transactionMessageID
    {
        get { return TransActionMessageID; }
        set { UserID = value; }
    }


    public static IQueryable<TransactionLog> LoadLogs(List<Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>>> predicates)
    {
        iThNkContextDataContext db = new iThNkContextDataContext();
        var LogList = db.TransactionLogs.AsQueryable();

        foreach (Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>> pred in predicates)
        {
            LogList = LogList.Where(pred);
        }

        List<TransactionLog> result = LogList.ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

I have no idea what im doing wrong
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well what happens with the code you've presented? And why are you calling `AsQueryable()`, when `db.TransactionLogs` should be compatible with `IQueryable<T>` already?

Comment: the reason for adding the .AsQueryable() is so that i can use the expression tree, the standard query is IEnumerable not IQueryable.

Comment: It really shouldn't be. If it is, that means all your filtering is going to be performed on the client side. If you're using a `DataContext`, I'd expect a `Table<TransactionLog>`.

Comment: So How would i go about writing this correctly?

Comment: You still haven't told us what's going wrong - but you really should look at what your `iThNkContextDataContext.TransactionLogs` property returns.

Comment: oh haha the error im getting is ErrorSystem.Linq.IQueryable<iThNkContext.TransactionLog>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,int,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another `TransactionLog` class somewhere? Are your expression trees *definitely* referring to `iThNkContext.TransactionLog`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Jon Skeet.

I got confused between my tables and classes.

My code now look as follows

```
List<Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>>> predicates = new List<Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>>>();
        iThNkContextDataContext db = new iThNkContextDataContext();

        if (Convert.ToInt32(cboAccount.SelectedValue) != -1)
        {
            predicates.Add(p => p.AccountID == Convert.ToInt32(cboAccount.SelectedValue));
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt32(cboSite.SelectedValue) != -1)
        {
            predicates.Add(p => p.SiteID == Convert.ToInt32(cboSite.SelectedValue));
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt32(cboMessage.SelectedValue) != -1)
        {
            predicates.Add(p => p.TransactionMessageID == Convert.ToInt32(cboMessage.SelectedValue));
        }

        var result = db.TransactionLogs.AsQueryable();

        foreach (Expression<Func<TransactionLog, bool>> pred in predicates)
        {
            result = result.Where(pred);
        }

        rgLog.DataSource = result.ToList();
```